# Does the attempted invasion of Midgard by Frost Giants figure into any Nordic myth?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, mythology, asgardians

As we learn in the first *Thor* movie and in episodes of *Agents of SHIELD*, many of the stories of the Norse gods on Earth were likely influenced by early interactions with Asgardians. Lady Sif mentions one time that there was a possibility of Asgardian-Midgardian interaction.

From the conversation between Lady Sif and Agent Coulson in Yes Men (S01E15):

> **Lady Sif**: The Frost Giants tried to conquer your Earth a millennia ago, but Asgard drove them away.

Given that many stories of Odin, Thor, and Asgard found their way into our mythology, it seems plausible (even likely) that a great battle for Midgard might also show up in mythology.

I'm particularly interested in real-world mythology, but if the myth/references only show up within the comics/MCU, then so be it.

Comment: **All** the Nordic Gods are supposed to die in the battle at the end of the world: Ragnarok.

Comment: @Oldcat no, just the popular ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Norse Mythology has **Ysetur**, a outlook fortress built by the Gods to keep watch on the Jotun to the north of Midgard, and keep them from invading Midgard. Without much happening there, it was eventually handed over to the Elves instead. Mythological Giants cared more about taking over Asgard than Midgard.